# Unable to add a third node in riak - This node is already a member of a cluster

Tags: riak

I have 2 nodes inside a riak ring. I tend to add third node

### 172.30.1.252

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-252:~/riak$ sudo riak-admin status | grep ring_members
ring_members : ['riak@172.30.1.250','riak@172.30.1.252']
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-252:~/riak$ sudo riak-admin cluster join riak@172.30.1.249
Failed: This node is already a member of a cluster
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-252:~/riak$
```

But, in my `172.30.1.249`, it doesn't join any other cluster.

### 172.30.1.249

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-249:~/riak$ sudo riak-admin cluster leave
Failed: 'riak@172.30.1.249' is the only member.
```

I event try to start and stop again.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-249:~/riak$ sudo riak stop
ok
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-249:~/riak$ sudo riak start
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 1024; 65536 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-249:~/riak$
```

But, I'm keep getting ***Failed: This node is already a member of a cluster*** when I try to execute `join` command from **172.30.1.252**

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute join from 172.30.1.249.

`sudo riak-admin cluster join riak@172.30.1.252`

Riak is right, 172.30.1.252 is already a member of ['riak@172.30.1.250','riak@172.30.1.252'].